# Beginning books on stochastic calculus and finance

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-calculus, mathematical-finance

my background is mathematics i would like to do research in financial mathematics. So I read some part of wilmott's book but it required stochastic calculus. I did not understand that book. So which books are suitable for me for beginning in stochastic calculus and finance?

Answer (score 2):

Shreve, Stochastic Calculus for Finance, volumes 1 and 2.